# ¿Como puedo solucionar el envio a una API por PUT?

Tags: php, api

Estoy tratando de enviar mediante una api de facturación a un metodo put, pero desde un archivo `php` pero me retorna en pantalla, `boolean(falso)`y el método que aparece es `GET`.

[image: imagen de referencia]

```
<?php

$url = "...";

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array(
   "Accept: application/json",
   "Authorization: token",
   "Content-Type: application/json",
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$data = <<<DATA
{
  "plan": "free",
  "environment": "beta",
  "sol_user": "leenhcrft",
  "sol_pass": "bustamante_fernandez",
  "ruc": "10761441519",
  "razon_social": "12345678901",
  "direccion": "NC",
  "certificado": "",
  "logo": ""
}
DATA;

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

//for debug only!
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($resp);

?>
```

Comment: Dos comentarios: 1.- El GET que ves en el DevTools es por cargar el `PHP` que ejecuta el `curl`. 2.- Asegurate de que el `sol_pass` (y los demas datos) no sean reales. En caso contrario, deberías cambiarlos en la config. del servicio.